In a Windows Server 2022 context, how can I share a printer in a selective way accessing only by RDP?
In a Windows Server 2022 context, how I can share printer in a selective way only by RDP?.
The users access to a server via .rdp (remote access) and the server already have installed two printer (color and B/W). Then the goal is a the specific user can use a specific printer accessing only by RDP.
For example:
the user 1 and user 3 they can use only B/W printer
the user 2 and 4 they can use both printer
the user 5 can only can use the color printer.
In my lab I try to develop an Organizational Unit. But it doesn't work. Also tried modifying some GPO. Also does not work.
